# Databricks-connect with Python + Scala UDF in JAR file not working locally

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to use a JAR file in python (using Databricks-connect) in Vs Code.

I already checked the path to the jar file.

I have the following code as example:

```
import datetime
import time
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyDataHub import LoadProcessorBase, ProcessItem
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, sha1, concat, udf, array
from pyspark.sql import functions
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType, IntegerType, DoubleType, StringType
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import sha1, upper
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column, _to_seq


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.jars", "/users/Phill/source/jar/DataHub_Core_Functions.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

def PhillHash(col):
  f = sc._jvm.com.narato.datahub.core.HashContentGenerator.getGenerateHashUdf()
  return  upper(sha1(Column(f.apply(_to_seq(sc, [col], _to_java_column)))))

sc._jsc.addJar("/users/Phill/source/jar/DataHub_Core_Functions.jar")

spark.range(100).withColumn("test", PhillHash("id")).show()
```

Any help would be appreciated cause I'm out of options here...

The error I get is the following:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar to a dbfs location and update the path accordingly. The workers cannot connect to your local filesystem.

Also make sure you are running version 5.4 of the databricks runtime (or higher).